# Managing Openshift cluster with Python

Tags: openshift, kubernetes-python-client

I have a requirement to use Python to deploy some things to an Openshift cluster (I've been pre-empted from any other solution), so I'm attempting to exercise the `kubernetes` module:

```
from kubernetes import client, config
configuration = client.Configuration()
configuration.username='admin'
configuration.password='redacted'
configuration.host='https://api.cluster.example.com:6443'
configuration.verify_ssl = False
v1 = client.CoreV1Api(client.ApiClient(configuration))
ns = {}
ns['kind'] = 'Namespace'
ns['apiVersion'] = 'v1'
ns['metadata'] = {}
ns['metadata']['name'] = 'mynamespace'
v1.create_namespace(ns)
```

Sadly, the v1 object doesn't authenticate to the cluster with the username / password I've given it:

```
kubernetes.client.rest.ApiException: (403)
Reason: Forbidden
HTTP response headers: HTTPHeaderDict({'Audit-Id': 'd59bb32d-a114-4b42-90ca-86c6315809d0', Cache-Control': 'no-cache, private', 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'X-Content-Type-ptions': 'nosniff', 'X-Kubernetes-Pf-Flowschema-Uid': '58a1456a-ff43-47a6-9a08-4a682ad5a509', X-Kubernetes-Pf-Prioritylevel-Uid': 'efbe11a3-861b-46ec-8e4a-1eadb766e284', 'Date': 'Thu, 21 Jan 2021 19:17:31 GMT', 'Content-Length': '273'})
HTTP response body: {"kind":"Status","apiVersion":"v1","metadata":{},"status":"Failure","message":"namespaces is forbidden: User \"system:anonymous\" cannot create resource \"namespaces\" in API group \"\" at the cluster scope","reason":"Forbidden","details":{"kind":"namespaces"},"code":403}
```

I'm looking for a way to throw configuration YAML at the OCP cluster and have it stick...

Comment: There apparently have been [some issues](https://github.com/openshift/openshift-restclient-python/issues/249) with username/password authentication against openshift. Token based authentication works great (and I can confirm that because I use that in my own Python code). Reading through that linked issue...*maybe* it should be fixed in current releases of the `kubernetes` module? I can't test myself, since it's not possible to password authenticate against our openshift environment (we use SSO via openid).

Comment: Agreeing with comment above, you should 100% be using token-based authentication with a long-lived token from a Service Account with necessary permissions within the cluster.

Comment: I've tried to use token auth (I'd prefer that myself), but because of the environment I'm in I can't guarantee having a valid kubeconfig file and I've not been able to get a token otherwise.